# Error importing pygtk with Anaconda

Tags: pygtk, anaconda

OS: Ubuntu 15.10

I had no problem importing pygtk with default Python interpreter.  However I wasn't able to do so using the Anaconda interpreter.

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import pygtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

I also couldn't get it to work after installing the pygtk with conda.

```
/opt/anaconda2/pkgs$ conda info --env
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /opt/anaconda2

/opt/anaconda2/pkgs$ conda list -n root|grep pygtk
pygtk                     2.16.0                        1    ska
```

As you can see from the output that pygtk pkg is available under the root env.

Any ideas what I have missed or done incorrectly?

Comment: I am having the same issue with of not being able to import pygtk even though it is visible under conda list. I am using Anaconda 2.5.0 and pygtk 2.16.0. Please let me know if you were able to figure this issue out. Thank you.

Comment: Could any solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've haven't had success with `ska/pygtk`, but `mw/pygtk2` worked for me:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/mw pygtk2
```

Other details [here](https://charmie11.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/pygtk-installation-using-anaconda/)